# integer = c lg n (inputs of size n, Cormen 3rd, page 23)?

Tags: algorithms, encoding-scheme

I just started with my "Algorithms" course. But my CS-background is lower than that of an average CS-student (I'm a data science student). Only had intro-2-prog course (Python/Java), that's it.

Cormen states on page 23: "...when working with inputs of size n, we typically assume that integers are represented by c lg n bits..."

- How is " c lg n " derived? It's relation to the input size?
- What calculation/proof is made here?
- Which assumptions should one have to come to this assumption?
- Which CS-field/subject (or academic/uni course?) works/operates with this notation, that should be learned prior to the "Algorithms" couse?

Comment: Logarithms are taught in high school hereabouts.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`lg n` is the base-`2` logarithm of `n`, satisfying `2^lg n = n`, so about `lg n` bits (`ceil lg n` to be exact) are needed for integers that can represent `0..n-1`, which suffices for pointers into the input. The authors of CLRS are saying that the word size should be about this much (`c lg n`). This is arguably reasonable because `c lg n`-bit words index storage of `n^c` (so any polynomial in `n`), and `c lg n`-bit operations can be synthesized from `lg n`-bit operations in constant time. If we make the word size much bigger, then the implied data-parallelism starts to distort running times.

The mathematical preliminaries here should be covered in an intro discrete mathematics class.